# How to query an array of JSON in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Tags: json, postgresql

I created a table named 'delivery' and one of its field is an array of JSON.

```
CREATE TABLE delivery
(
  id text NOT NULL,
  date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  items json NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT delivery_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And here are the example data:

```
"1", "2012-01-08 20:54:38.541989+00", "[ {"id":1, "qty": 10 }, {"id":2, "qty": 300}]"
"2", "2012-01-08 22:44:10.016285+00", "[ {"id":1, "qty": 200}]"
```

How can I get the rows where the 'id' within the 'items' field is equal to 1?

Comment: 1) using a text column for a primary key (where an integer could be possible) can be considered bad design. 2) putting repeating groups inside a blob-like object (such as json) violates 1NF and can be considered bad design, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using subquery and json fucntions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM delivery
WHERE '1' in (
   select a->>'id' from json_array_elements(items) a
)
```

Here is SQL [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8886/8) to play with.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM delivery WHERE items->>'id' = 1
```

Comment: I tried this one but it gives error. It looks like you can't directly parse/access an array of JSON.