# Trying to query a JSON array of non-objects in Postgresql 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to query a table with a JSON column which will always hold an array of "primitive" values (i.e. integers, strings, booleans -- not objects or arrays).

My query should be similar to [ref2], but I can't do `->>'id'` because I'm not trying to access a JSON object but the value itself.

In the [ref1] fiddle (blatant fork from the above), there's and incomplete query... *I'd like to query all `things` which contain `3` among its values*.

Even more so, I'd like some rows to have arrays of strings, other rows to have arrays of integers, and other ones arrays of booleans... So casting is undesiderable.

I believe `->>` returns the original JSON value type, but I need the "root" object... That is, my JSON value is `[1,2,3,4]`, using `json_array_elements` should yield e.g. `2`, but that is a JSON type according to my tests.

Upgrading to 9.4 is planned in the near future, but I haven't read anything yet that gave me a clue `jsonb` would help me.

UPDATE: at the moment, I'm (1) making sure all values are integers (mapping non-integers values to integers), which is suboptimal; (2) querying like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM things, json_array_elements(things.values) AS vals
  WHERE vals.value::text::integer IN (1,2,3);
```

I need the double casting (otherwise it complains that `cannot cast type json to integer`).

ref1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5febb/1

ref2: [How to query an array of JSON in PostgreSQL 9.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733196/how-to-query-an-array-of-json-in-postgresql-9-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `json_array_elements` you can unpack the array with `generate_series`, using the `->>` operator to extract a text representation.

```
SELECT things.*
FROM things
CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, json_array_length(values) - 1) AS idx
WHERE values ->> idx = '1'
GROUP BY things.id;
```

This is a workaround for the lack of `json_array_elements_text` in 9.3.

You need an `operator(=)` for json to do this without either messing with casting or relying on the specific textual representations of integers, booleans, etc. `operator(=)` is only available for `jsonb`. So in 9.3 you're stuck with using the text representation (so `1.00` won't `=` `1`) or casting to a PostgreSQL type based on the element type.

In 9.4 you could use `to_json` and the jsonb `operator(=)`, e.g.:

```
SELECT things.*
    FROM things
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, json_array_length(values) - 1) AS idx
    WHERE (values -> idx)::jsonb = to_json(1)::jsonb
    GROUP BY things.id;

 id |             date              | values  
----+-------------------------------+---------
  1 | 2015-08-09 04:54:38.541989+08 | [1,2,3]
(1 row)
```

Comment: For 9.4+, the containment operators give somewhat simpler solutions, like `values::jsonb @> jsonb '1' OR values::jsonb @> jsonb '"foo"'`